# spawn processes inside a loop based on completed

Tags: unix

I have the below code and i am trying to get atleast 4 processes running at any point of time. First time 4 processes kick off and ps -ef checks how many completed, if for example 3 are running, the loop dynamically needs to pick up one process from the array and run. Can someone please help me with this,

arr=("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")

tLen=${#arr[@]}

for (( i=1; i< ${tLen}; i++ ));

do

for((j=i; j<=i+3; j++));

do

nohup  sh script.sh ${arr[$j]} &

cnt = `ps -ef| grep scriptname | grep seqname | wc -l`

//need to include logic that can spawn process based on the number of count returned, (no of processes to spawn = 4 - cnt)

done

i=j+1

done**

Answer (score 0):

The while loop inside waits untill the number of processes running goes under 4, then spawns other processes in the array.

arr=("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")

tLen=${#arr[@]}

```
i=0
while (i<tLen)
do
cnt = `ps -ef| grep scriptname | grep seqname | wc -l`
    while (cnt -eq 4)
    do
    echo "no of process running `ps -ef| grep scriptname | grep seqname | wc -l`"
    sleep 10s
    cnt = `ps -ef| grep scriptname | grep seqname | wc -l`
    done
//chk for failures and spawn next process
 nohup  sh script.sh ${arr[$i]} &
i=i++
done
```